# Android ListView with RadioButton

Tags: android, radiobuttonlist

As simple as this seems I have not been able to find an easy way solution to this, I have a simple radio button list view and I want to extract the value of the radio button selected on button click event.

Here is the code you might have seen in a million other places.

```
 public class RadioListActivity extends ListActivity {
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, CONTENT));

    final ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}

private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] {"bla1","bla2","bla3","bla4","bla5"};
}
```

ANY help is appreciated! :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in two simple lines of codes which I had to scavenge for days at end.

Just adding the below two lines to the onClick event will extract the index of the item selected along with the value at it!

```
              ListView l=getListView();
              Object obj=l.getItemAtPosition(l.getCheckedItemPosition());
```

Hope someone finds the above helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> extract the value of the radio button selected on button click event.

you can get selected value from ListView using `ListView.getSelectedItemPosition`  as on Button click:

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
        int selectedindex=RadioListActivity.this.
                            getListView().getSelectedItemPosition();

        String str_selectedtxt=CONTENT[selectedindex];    
  }
```

Comment: It throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ( :length=14; index=-1, or some random gibberish). Any help?

Comment: @GarimaTiwari : hi Garima , just put index check condition before getting value from Array. you are getting error bez maybe possible no item is selected in ListView

Comment: For whatever value im selecting in the radio list it throws the SAME error I posted above. Can you post the code for the index check condition you're talking about? I didnt quite get you on that.

Comment: I think the code should be getCheckedItemPosition() instead of selected. Anyway +1 for the effort! :)